# ASP.Net website makes browser load unwanted (non-referenced) plugins

Tags: asp.net, plugins, reference

I've found that some of my ASP.Net web apps prompt the browser to load plugins that I'm not explicitely using and certainly haven't deliberately referenced in the project settings.

Two that come to mind are for MS MediaPlayer and the "SVG Viewer for Netscape".

The only commonality I've determined so far is that the two sites/apps affected both use Master pages (nested in some cases).

We don't use SVG file types (just the normal mix of jpg/gif/png) and no video/audio (not yet anyway).

Can anyone provide a hint as to where the references for these might be creeping in?  e.g. Is it a server-level include? Or a .Net runtime default when using master pages?

Does anyone else even experience this, or is it just me?

No urgency, I'd just like to remove it if possible.

Thanks.

Al

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page source in your browser, you should see what's in the page that requires a plugin. If you load external Javascript, you will have to look at that too. Do you have ads on the site that include 3rd party code?